# Listen Battery charging state in Android 8 and 6 (background)?

Tags: android

What is the best way to listen to charging state in Android 8 and 6 in background?

Since implicit broadcasts (ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED and ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED) are not allowed anymore.

Comment: When you mean background you mean when your app is not on the screen right?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I mean

Answer (score 0):

This is very theoretical  but you could try to make a long running `Service` that registers the two restricted `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` intents. Then this service can "repackage" the intents information using a non restricted intent, and pass it on to your main app.